# Div inside div, background resizing not working (using parallax effect)?

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design, parallax

At first, sorry for my english :-)

I am trying to redesign my blog completely. It has to be responsive and I want to integrate parallax effects in my header (that is why I am using the picture as background and not as image tag). Parallax works already, but I have a problem with the second layer "header-title". If I resize the window my header background resizes its width and height automatically but the "header-title" layer doesn't.

Here you can see the Problem: http://jsfiddle.net/utkcT/

```
    <div id="header" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
    <div id="header-title">
        Dieser Text ist zentriert!
    </div>
</div>

    #header{
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-image: url("http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/411/cache/northern-lights-picture-aurora-borealis-september-2011-yukon_41173_600x450.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    }

#header-title{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    width:100%; 
    height:500px;
    padding-top:25%;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    }

      $(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $('#header-title').height($('#header').height());
    });


    // ---------------PARALLAX FUNCTION ------------------------    

    $('data-type="background"').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
        }); 
    }); 


});
```

I tried already to fix it with Javascript/JQuery as you see, but it doesn't work because "header-title" is inside of the "header" tag.

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: You should avoid calc dimensions using Javascript. I don't really understand your issue but what about background-size: cover; ?

Comment: Can you explain what your issue is and what your trying to achieve I'm not sure i fully understand?

Comment: @JimboJones The Problem is I have 2 divs with id's "header" and "header-title". One of them has a picture as a background (background-size: contain;) and has a parallax effect. The Other one has a background color, which is on the top more transparency and on the bottom less transparency. In the usual resolution they look good, but if I resize the window and do it smaller, the problem is that the height of "header" is smaller then the heigh of "header-title". For more understanding I show you both situations in the picture. http://s14.directupload.net/images/140211/ez98lm2i.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure if i have fully understood but here a shot at it!

I have firstly changed the image as the one specified tricked me with the URL thinking it was 600px by 450px.

But as it turns out it was 600px by 404px, so anyway image replace. What I have done is replaced changed as follows:

Header Title - Now a relatively positioned div with 100%. Within this div I have put a transparent image, this one is 12px by 9px so once its stretched it is 650px by 450px as per the background image. If you change the image then you will have to update the transparent spacer.

This spacer then when enlarged will forced the height to the same as the background. thus no need to set the height of the div.

Within this I have wrapped a div around the text, positioned this absolutely within the header title div.

```
<div id="header" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
    <div id="header-title">
        <img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/2qcnwn9.png" id="spacer-img" />
        <div id="header-text">Dieser Text ist zentriert!</div>
    </div>
</div>


#header{
    width:100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-image: url("http://www.reactive.com/Media/images/hero-ripcurl-01-2615749e-fba2-47da-abc7-d0ea3a9ecfbd-0-600x450.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
}

#spacer-img{
    width:100%; 
    display:block;
}

#header-text{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:25%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}


#header-title{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    width:100%; 
    position:relative;
}
```

see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/utkcT/2/

hopefully that is what you were looking to achieve.